# Unable to SaveChanges on a db update. Weird lazy loading behavior possibly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Right now, my code looks as simple as this:

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext db;

    public FooController()
    {
        db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    public ActionResult Update(int id) 
    {
        Foo foo = db.Foos.Find(id);
        foo.X = "new string";
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Redirect("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

Assume Foo has a property X, a string, and a property Bars, a collection of Bar entities. There is a constraint on the property that there must be between 1 to 100 Bars in the collection.

I am currently getting the following exception:

```
Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.
```

which I debugged and printed out the actual error:

```
Property: "Bars", Error: "Must have between 1 and 100 bars"
```

This confused me since I knew that that particular instance of `foo` had 5 Bars in its collection. So I put a breakpoint on the `db.SaveChanges()` line and used the VS tool to hover over the foo instance and discovered it did indeed have the 5 Bars in the collection. When I continued running the program, the Update successfully completed. At first I thought, that's weird. Maybe there's a low level race condition (I say low level because I'm not doing any async/threading at the app level) and the breakpoint allowed the other thread to catch up. That is, until I ran the update again with the breakpoint *without* hovering over the foo instance, waiting a few seconds, and continued the running of the program. The error returned.

So I think I'm loading something lazily when I hover over `foo` and that load is necessary for saving changes. Is this a known issue? Is there some other part of the code that I should post to figure out what's going on?

Edit: For a temporary workaround, and in case this adds more evidence. The following addition allows the method to work as intended:

```
public ActionResult Update(int id) 
{
    Foo foo = db.Foos.Find(id);
    foo.X = "new string";
    Debug.WriteLine(foo.Bars);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Clearly this is a bandaid, and I'd like to know what's really going on here.

Another Edit: Adding how validation is implemented on Foo.Bars

```
public class Foo 
{
    public string X {get;set;}

    [MinMaxLength]
    public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars {get; set;}
}
```

And MinMaxLength looks as follows:

```
public class MinMaxLength : ValidationAttribute
{
    public int Min { get; set; } = 1;
    public int Max { get; set; } = 100;

    public MinMaxLength()
        : base("Must have between 1 and 100")
    {

    }

    public MinMaxLength(string errorMessage)
        : base(errorMessage)
    {

    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        var coll = value as ICollection;
        if (coll == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var count = coll.Count;
        return count >= Min && count <= Max;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @trashr0x your comment lead me to read more about that statement (as well as DbSet.Attach) and when to use it. I'm wondering if I should actually use DbSet.Attach(foo) instead though, since I am only updating one simple column.

Comment: Nevermind, that did not solve my problem. The error still presents itself if I use either of those two options.

Comment: Have you tried including `Bars` in the query? i.e. replacing `Find()` with `db.Foos.Include(x => x.Bars).SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);`

Comment: Yes, I have now and it does solve the issue (but again, moreso like a bandaid). It may add an unnecessary performance hit if Bars is big enough and update is being called a lot. I know I would normally say worry about performance only when it's an issue, but I would rather not add unnecessary loads as a workaround.

Comment: Could you include a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for this question? Its pretty hard to debug psychically. It isn't obvious how you are running Validation on your models, and how it is failing. Not is it obvious the lifecycle of your DbContext

Comment: I don't really know how to get any more MVCE than what I have provided. I have just added how the context is being created (I am not disposing it anywhere) if that helps, but I doubt it will since it's quite basic in its implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
Foo foo = db.Foos.Find(id);
if (foo != null)
{
    foo.X = "new string";
    db.Foos.Attach(foo);
    var entry = db.Entry(foo);
    entry.Property(x => x.X).IsModified = true;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

This should generate the following SQL:

```
UPDATE    dbo.Foos
SET       X = 'new string'
WHERE     Id = @fooId
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution. Can get pretty nasty if you start dealing with attaching and manually setting property changes. I've been there and it is not pretty. Also, imagine having to do this all over the place.

Comment: You don't have to do it all over the place. For example, assuming a repository pattern, you could create a generic update method on your repository, passing in `T` for your entity and `Expression<Func<T, object>>` for the entity's property which is to be updated.

Comment: Sure, this is better. When I said this is not a good solution wasn't your code, but EF workaround. Why would I need to care to set stuff as unchanged. EF should be smart enough. Very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
public ActionResult Update(int id) 
{
    Foo foo = db.Foos.Find(id);
    foo.X = "new string";

    var entry = db.Entry(foo);
    entry.State = EntityState.Modified;

    db.SaveChanges();

    // Rest of code
}
```